# Copy a web form with Values to the same page

Tags: asp.net

I have a `request.aspx` page where the user enters values into some textboxes and submits it. Now we want to have a copy feature where all values of the existing request are copied to a new request page upon a button click.
So basically the existing request URL looks like 
`http://localhost:1122/UI/Request.aspx?id=49609&found=true` and for a new request, it looks as `http://localhost:1122/UI/Request.aspx`. In this case, we want to copy all the value sof request ID 49609 to the new request page.
So far I have included a button and stored a flag indicating that its a copy action from user upon button click.

```
 protected void btnCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ViewState["UserCopied"] = true;
            Response.Redirect("Request.aspx");
        }
```

and `btncopy`  is on `request.aspx` page.
Now I am not sure how to reload the same page with the existing request values. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: This is the default behaviour in ASP.NET

Comment: What is default behavior?